# Enum variable as a template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, enums

I have a enum class:

```
enum class flipping_t {
    eNone,
    eHorizontal,
    eVertical
};
```

Then I'm trying to use its values as a template parameters:

```
template<flipping_t>
void areas();


template<>
void areas<flipping_t::eHorizontal>();


template<>
void areas<flipping_t::eVertical>();
```

My app has a variable of type `flipping_t`:

```
auto flip = flipping_t::eNone;
```

I want to change its value depending on which key has just been pressed down (I'm working on simple photo editor so want to mirror a picture)

Then I'm invoking a function according to current `flip`:

```
areas<flip>();
```

And compiler says:

> no instance of function template "areas" matches the argument

I understand why `areas<flipping_t::eNone>()` works fine. I'm looking for a way to fix `areas<flip>()`

Comment: I am not sure we have all the details to help you, but from what it seems, it looks like you are trying to pass a variable as a template argument, which you can't do. Template arguments (by that, I mean anything that goes between the <> of the template definition) must be known at compiletime. You can't do `auto foo = enum::value; area<foo>;`

Comment: Unfortunately, the current design doesn't work as you think. Template parameter type (non-template here) must be known at the compile time. `auto foo = enum::value;` is run time-dependent and hence can not be used. You need either a run-time design or maybe a mechanism to convert the run-time information to compile time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A template parameter can be of an integral type, what `flipping_t` is, but is shall be a constant. That is the reason why `areas<flipping_t::eNone>()` works fine: `areas<flipping_t::eNone>()` is indeed a (compile time) constant.

But when you declare `auto flip = flipping_t::eNone;`, `flip` is a *variable*, and its values is allowed to change at run time. That is the reason why you cannot use it as a template parameter.

If it can be constant, you could say it to the compiler:

```
    const auto flip = flipping_t::eHorizontal;
```

This is enough to later be able to use `areas<flip>()`. But in that case, `flip` is nothing more than an alias to `flipping_t::eHorizontal`